# Unable to activate GDAL Georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I have installed QGIS 2.14 on my MacBook Air, but am unable to activate the "Georeferencer GDAL" plugin.  When I open the "Manage and Install Plugins" dialog, the Georeferencer GDAL plugin is listed under Installed, but it is not activated.  I tried clicking on the checkbox for the plugin, but that has no effect.  Same for all of the other plugins listed as installed but not activated.  (Also, the uninstall and reinstall buttons are disabled.)

How can I activate georeferencing?

[image: screen shot of manage plugins dialog]

Comment: I assume you are using the [Kyng Chaos version](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). Have you installed the [GDAL Framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) ?